# Cucumber parallel execution issue with browser quit & threads

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to upgrade cucumber to use parallel execution with TestNg. However I am facing issues with browser quit.

I set the browser instances to 3 in pom.xml as below

```
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>3</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
```

1) After execution sometimes I see 1 or 2 browsers are not quit. Though it is executing quit method in hooks(Shown in below code).

2) Other issue is for 3 scenarios I am printing thread id at the start

```
System.out.println("Start Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

However the I see thread Id printed only for 2 instances though its executing all 3 scenarios in 3 different browsers. 
But for the quit browser code in hooks I see thread id printed for all 3 browsers.

hooks has below code:

```
@After(order = 2)
public void takeScreenShot(Scenario scenario) {
    byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) util.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
}

@After(order = 1)
public void createTestRun(Scenario scenario) {
  <Some piece of code>
}

@After(order = 0)
public void validate(Scenario scenario) {
    if (!scenario.isFailed()) {
        LOGGER.info("Log something");
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Test Failed");
        if (world.orderType != null) {
            SupportMethods.printErrors();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("QUIT Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId()); // I see this ID is being called every time
    util.driver.quit(); 
}
```

util class has below code:

```
public class util {
    public static WebDriver driver;   
<some piece of code> 
}
```

In webdriver code I am assigning chrome instance to this util class driver

```
util.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Don't make your drivers static! Use DI to share state (an instance of your util class) between steps: http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer

Comment: @mpkorstanje There are many references of static in the framework, I guess this issue will be there even if I remove static driver? Is there any other better way?

Comment: Nope. You simply can not run in parallel if you have static references. They are shared between threads which is what you don't want. You'll have to refactor your test framework to use DI first.

Comment: @mpkorstanje Ok Thanks

Comment: @mpkorstanje Is there any way we can control thread count through maven command or pass from some where?